# Show crystal report in another folder using mvc web app

Tags: model-view-controller, crystal-reports, report

My Crystal report is in a separate location. I want to show that the report using web app.i has already installed CR runtime and Crystal report for a visual studio in my local machine. But when I host it on my server I need to install CR runtime and Crystal report for visual studio. But I was unable to install the Crystal  report for visual studio because there is no visual studio installed in a server. Give error "you must already install visual studio 2010 or other. How can I solve this?

Is there any way to install crystal report for Visual studio without installing visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. we have to install some nuget packages.First install [Install-Package CrystalReports.Engine -Version 13.0.3500] and install related dependencies.
Follow the following link 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalReports.Engine/

Then you have to install CR Runtime 
Change the the bitness of project to 64